# Summer programs for European undergraduate mathematicians

Tags: undergraduate, summer-school, extracurricular

There are many summer programs in the US, aimed at motivated undergraduate students of mathematics, that offer *lectures* and *mini-courses* on a variety of topics. However, as far as I know, most programs require that the applicant is American or a permenant resident in the US.

My question:

> Are there any such summer programs in the US, Europe, Asia, South America,
>   or Africa to which a European student can apply?

Comment: Just to note: similar questions regarding the REUs (rather than lecture courses) were discussed at math.SX and MO

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/summer-programs-to-gain-research-experience-as-an-undergraduate-outside-the-uni

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13847/research-experience-for-undergraduates-summer-programs

Also while it is not exactly *summer* exchange, in Europe you may be eligible for Erasmus student exchanges (see e.g. http://www.esn.org/content/erasmus-programme )

Comment: @just-learning Thank you for pointing out those threads.

Comment: Are you sure this is required in the US? Of course, there are visa issues, but a polite email to check takes two minutes to write and can be sent out a hundred times ;)

Comment: Also, unless you are a first year, do not confine your interest to "undergraduate" programmes. There are a lot of introductory graduate programmes that actually would be fine for a bright undergraduate. I went on such a summer school before I applied for my PhD position and at a minimum it gave me something to talk about in the interview.

Comment: @Calchas A lot of things are funded by US government agencies, which often require you be a US citizen or permanent resident. So if you aren't, funding would have to come from elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know about Maths but I did a similar course in materials when I was an undergrad (in UK). I don't recall there being any nationality requirements so I expect they do exist.

Comment: @cpast, not true, I am neither, but a wedge of my funding for summer programmes used to come from NNSA in the DoE: exactly the kind of agency you would assume would have a pretty strict US citizen requirement. It is always worth checking because many people will make the same assumptions. There is always money swilling around somewhere, you just need to find it!

Comment: @Calchas "often"

Answer (score 2):

[Park City summer program](https://pcmi.ias.edu/program-index/2015) organized by the IAS (Institute for Advanced Study, Princeton) is worth trying. In particular, they have Undergraduate Summer School. Here is [their Application procedure](https://pcmi.ias.edu/application-ugss).

However, non-US permenant resident/citizens may have to pay more as in their web page

> Undergraduates funded by PCMI may receive lodging, travel, meals and a stipend (stipends are awarded to U.S. Citizens or U.S. permanent residents only).

Please note that the application deadline for 2015 is already passed (January 31, 2015).